# error in use @preg_replace . What wrong in my code?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

i write this code to replace $TheWhiteList to null string in message and show it to screen.
but it not work. Can you tell me where I was wrong?

```
$TheWhiteList = Array
('http://facebook.com',
'google.com',
'facebook.com',
'stackoverflow.com',
);

$message ='test test tes tes [URL=http://facebook.com]http://facebook.com[/URL]
[URL=http://facebook.com]http://facebook.com[/URL]
[URL]http://stackoverflow.com[/URL]
[URL]http://facebook.com[/URL]
[URL]http://google.com[/URL]';
$string = '';
    if(!empty($TheWhiteList))
    {
        foreach ($TheWhiteList as $value)
        {

                $string .= '|';

            $string .=preg_quote($value);
        }

        $pattern = '#\[url=[\'\"]('.$string.')[\'\"]\].*\[\/url\]#imsU';

        $replace = null;

        $message = @preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $message);
    }
    print_r($message);
```

anyone please help me

Comment: I've never seen `@preg_replace`. Shouldn't it be just `preg_replace`?

Comment: @chade_ `@` is used to suppress errors.

Comment: @mega6382 My fault, sorry! :$

Comment: @chade_   (`@preg_replace`)   to suppress errors

Answer (score 1):

In your regex you require the URL to be surrounded by quotes but in the test input the URL comes unquoted after `URL=`. Hence no match is found and no replacement takes place.

Comment: threre ` [URL=http://facebook.com]http://facebook.com[/URL]` in my code

Comment: Exactly. Notice there is no quote after `=` and in the regex a quote is mandatory: `url=[\'\"]...`. The same at the end of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

I found two problems.

$string .= '|'; this adds an extra '|' at first.
and '\" not marked as optional.

change

```
$string .= '|';
```

to

```
if( $string ) {
   $string .= '|';
}
```

and pattern to

```
$pattern = '#\[url=[\'\"]?('.$string.')[\'\"]?\].*\[\/url\]#imsU'
```

Comment: "thank" @tan Do you have a solution for it to work? help me

Comment: Did u tested pattern i given?

Comment: `#\[url=['\"](|http\://facebook\.com|google\.com|facebook\.com|xvideos\.com)['\"]\].*\[\/url\]#imsU` this value

Comment: it has to be #\[url=['\"]?(http\://facebook\.com|google\.com|facebook\.co‌​m|xvideos\.com)['\"]‌?​\].*\[\/url\]#imsU

Comment: @johndoes I've put ! in if condition by mistake. fixed that.